# How to use Bootstrap 'Dashboard' example in my Django project?

Tags: css, django, bootstrap-4

I currently use bootstrap components (4.3.1) but I would like to use a full example: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/examples/dashboard/

But there are not many explanations to use it, except to download source code but there are so many files that I am lost.
I've read the documentation (https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/getting-started/introduction/) but not really explained how to use full example...

Comment: Take a look at: https://github.com/zostera/django-bootstrap4

Comment: @sajjad rezaee: there is no 'doc' folder...

Comment: @sajjad rezaee: ok, thank, it works.

Comment: @first last: I try to install demo but it failed (error ```No module named 'bootstrap4'``` when running python manage.py migrate)... but django-bootstrap seems to be interresting...

Comment: did you run `pip install django-bootstrap4`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Download bootstrap 4.1.3 source files from [here](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/archive/v4.1.3.zip)

navigate to `site => docs => 4.1 => examples => dashboard`

this is the HTML file you need. as you open the HTML file in an editor there are some dependencies coming from the `dist` and `assets` folders. so you need them as well. you can find them by following the address in `index.html`